RBAC: Access Denied when deploying Kubeflow using already hosted Istio
We're deploying Kubeflow on an EKS cluster that already has both istio 1.23 and cert-manager installed on it.
We therefore skipped istio and cert-manager installation and used option 3 from oauth2 deployment as suggested by the docs[1]
Digging into the docs, the istio that's deployed along with the manifests uses Oauth as an authentication mechanism, given we already have Istio we worked that around by making the centraldashboard virtual service (answers at /) to point to the Oauth and then Oauth proxies the service to the actual centraldashboard.
Other than that, our ingress selector and the service account isn't istio-ingressgateway but istio-ingress only. We changed the AuthorizationPolicies to reflect so, but we're still getting RBAC: access denied.
Only when removing the Authorization Policy[2] for centraldashboard we're actually able to login, but it then fails to spin a notebook with the message "No user detected".
p.s.: I've tried updating the policy to allow requests from all namespaces, but failed with the same error
We're aware that we might tweak the requestauthentication as well, but we couldn't find docs on how to do that
Any help is largely appreciated
Given we already an load balancer ingress, we changed the Gateway to have https set
[1]https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#oauth2-proxy
[2] https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests/blob/master/apps/centraldashboard/upstream/overlays/istio/authorizationpolicy.yaml
